# How to find target data as next Wednesday at 1700 in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

We have a Parcel Delivery system that records parcels received to be delivered as  ParcelReceivedDate, a datetime field.

We have to define a target delivery date and time in a way that any parcel that is received on Saturday or Sunday must have a target delivery date as next Wednesday 1700 GMT.

```
 CASE 
     WHEN Priority = 'Normal' and DATENAME(weekday,ParcelReceivedDate) IN ('Saturday') 
     THEN ??

     WHEN Priority = 'Normal' and DATENAME(weekday,ParcelReceivedDate) IN ('Sunday')  
     THEN ??

     Else DATEADD(hour,24,ParcelReceivedDate)
 END as ParcelTargetDate
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check the syntax but the main road has traced ;)

Comment: Do you have, or could you create a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql)? This would be the easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN Priority = 'Normal' and DATENAME(weekday,ParcelReceivedDate) IN ('Saturday') 
    THEN
        dateadd(second, -datepart(second, ParcelReceivedDate), 
            dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, ParcelReceivedDate), 
                dateadd(hour, 17 - datepart(hour, ParcelReceivedDate), 
                    dateadd(day, 4, ParcelReceivedDate)
                )
            )
        )
    WHEN Priority = 'Normal' and DATENAME(weekday,ParcelReceivedDate) IN ('Sunday')  
    THEN
        dateadd(second, -datepart(second, ParcelReceivedDate), 
            dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, ParcelReceivedDate), 
                dateadd(hour, 17 - datepart(hour, ParcelReceivedDate), 
                    dateadd(day, 3, ParcelReceivedDate)
                )
            )
        )
    ELSE DATEADD(hour,24,ParcelReceivedDate
END as ParcelTargetDate
```

You know if you are on Saturday or Sunday so you add offset days to reach wednesday

Comment: The trouble is with Time that comes along with the date. for example  if the ParcelRecievedDate is 2013-12-21 12:00:00.000 then ParcelTargetDate should be 2013-12-25 17:00:00.000

Comment: @BIQuad: Have a nice day ;) Because you're newbie, if you want you can accept the answer clicking on the check